# Find and ST_JOIN all objects where names that starts with the same first two words

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table with polygons, who I would like to merge to one polygon if the name attribute starts with the same two words.

ANGELHOLM TMA SECTOR KLIPPAN,

ANGELHOLM TMA SECTOR LAHOLM,

ANKARA TMA, ANKARA TMA LOWER SECTOR,

ANKARA TMA UPPER SECTOR,

ANTALYA APP CARDAK UPPER SECTOR,

ANTALYA APP EAST MIDDLE SECTOR,

ANTALYA APP EAST MIDDLE SECTOR,

ANTALYA APP EAST UPPER SECTOR-,

ANTALYA APP NORTH LOWER SECTOR,

ANTALYA APP SOUTHEAST LOWER SE,

ANTALYA APP SOUTHWEST LOWER SE,

ANTALYA APP WEST MIDDLE SECTOR,

ANTALYA APP WEST UPPER SECTOR-,

ANTANANARIVO TMA,

ANTANANARIVO TMA

I.e I would like to use ST_Join (postgis command) on all objects that starts with
“ANTALAYA TMA%” to one polygon,

ANKARA TMA% to one polygon,

ANGELHOLM TMA%  to one polygon,

ANTALYA APP% to one polygon,

ANTANANARIVO TMA% to one polygon

etc.

The problem is that I don’t want to hardcode i.e ‘ANKARA TMA%’ since there are thousands of object/names in the table.
I would like to, in one query, make a comparison with the two first words in the name, which I don’t know anything of, and ST_JOIN them together.

Is it possible to do that in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `substring()` function with a `regular expression` in order to extract the two first words of your "tmaName" string. Because `ST_UNION()` is an aggregate function, you can try something like this :

```
SELECT substring(t1."tmaName" from '^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+') AS icaoCode
     , ST_MULTI(ST_UNION(ST_SnapToGrid(t1.the_geom, 0.000001))) AS geom
  FROM "TMA" AS t1
 GROUP BY substring(t1."tmaName" from '^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+')
```

The regular expression '^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+' selects the two first sets of characters which are not spaces separated by one space charater, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).

Comment: This is how I do it manually:
INSERT INTO "TMA" ("the_geom", "FACC_CODE") 
VALUES (
 (SELECT ST_MULTI(ST_UNION(ST_SnapToGrid(the_geom, 0.000001))) AS geom 
   FROM "TMA"
   WHERE "tmaName" ILIKE 'Friedrichshafen SECTOR A' OR "tmaName" ILIKE 'Friedrichshafen SECTOR B'
 ) ,'GA005');

Comment: And this is what I tried:
INSERT INTO "TMA" ("the_geom", "FACC_CODE") 
Values (
   (SELECT ST_MULTI(ST_UNION(ST_SnapToGrid(t1.the_geom, 0.000001))) AS geom
      FROM "TMA" AS t1
      INNER JOIN "TMA" AS t2
      ON substring(t1."tmaName" from '^\w\s\w') = substring(t2."tmaName" from '^\w\s\w')
      AND t1."tmaName" <> t2."tmaName"
   ), 'GA005');
Only one empty (all attributes) row is inserted.
I inserted "t1."the_geom instead of the_geom in snapToGrid because the_geom was
ambiguous.

Comment: @Paul - I've updated my answer which didn't fit your expectation, as it was only comparing two rows with the same two first words. The updated answer groups all the rows which share the same two first words, and it should work as `ST_UNION` sounds like an [aggregate function](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.1/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_Aggregate_Functions), but I've never used postgist so you will have to test and adapt the proposed solution to make it working.

Comment: I tried this:INSERT INTO "TMA" ("the_geom", "icaoCode") 
Values (
   (SELECT substring(t1."tmaName" from '^\w\s\w') AS first_key_words
     , ST_MULTI(ST_UNION(ST_SnapToGrid(t1.the_geom, 0.000001))) AS geom
  FROM "TMA" AS t1
 GROUP BY substring(t1."tmaName" from '^\w\s\w')
   ), 'GA005')  But got an error : ERROR:  sub question can only return 1 column
LINE 3:    (SELECT substring(t1."tmaName" from '^\w\s\w') AS first_k...

Comment: remove `substring(t1."tmaName" from '^\w\s\w') AS 2_first_key_words` from the `SELECT` clause, this was only for test purpose, not for you to make a copy/paste in your INSERT statement. And test first the SELECT statement alone before embedding it into the INSERT statement.

Comment: I tested the select statement and got only 3 rows, first row:  "first_key_words" = null, second row: "first_key_words" = 'N G' and last row: "first_key_words" = 'P G'. All three rows had a geometry. But there are hundreds of different "groups" that starts with the same two first words in the tmaName attribute.

Comment: Can't help with so few information. Please provide a full sample of data in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bcccd37c06c7759673458c22e6900850)  by creating the table, inserting a sample of rows and executing the query to share the result.

Comment: There are three rows starting with the tmaName 'P G MATANTE' and one row with tmaName 'N GAOUNDERE TMA'

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=49a34fe48d596eee37344177d0fef85f Here is the link, don't know if I did it correct

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your sample data in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0188bb1f1d9953371d8dc17ef08e4d7f). Can you retest in PostGist on your side with the new regular expression '^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+' ? By the way, in your sample data, there may be some inconsistencies, ie "AGADIR/AL-MASSIRA" can't match with "AGADIR/AL MASSIRA"

Comment: When I use your latest update i get the ERROR:  more then one row is retuned by the subquestion used as an expresion. when I trie to insert the result in a tabel.

Comment: Try this : `INSERT INTO "TMA" ("the_geom", "icaoCode") SELECT ST_MULTI(ST_UNION(ST_SnapToGrid(t1.the_geom, 0.000001))), 'GA005' FROM "TMA" AS t1 GROUP BY substring(t1."tmaName" FROM'^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+')`

Comment: Nice, but what if I would like to add the result of ("tmaName" FROM'^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+') in "icaoCode" instead of 'GA005'? I've also done the above with this: CREATE TABLE "TMA-tmp" AS
 WITH tmp  AS   (
  SELECT ST_MULTI(ST_UNION(ST_SnapToGrid(t1.the_geom, 0.000001))) AS geom
    FROM "TMA_org" AS t1
   GROUP BY substring(t1."tmaName" from '^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+')
   )
select * from tmp;

Comment: Did like this: Create table "TMA_tmp" as
 With tmp  as   (
  (SELECT substring(t1."tmaName" from '^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+') AS icaoCode , 
  ST_MULTI(ST_UNION(ST_SnapToGrid(t1.the_geom, 0.00001))) AS geom FROM "TMA_org" AS t1 
  GROUP BY substring(t1."tmaName" from '^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+')
  )
   )
select * from tmp;

Comment: @Paul - Happy if your problem is now solved. Thank you to vote on my answer if helpfull.